# PHP 8.1 Updating code which was using the each() function

Tags: php

I am updating my website from PHP 7.4 to PHP 8.1 but have issues with the deprecated each() function. The point of this is so the users gets the correct menu.

The original code looks like this

```
while (list($tmpkey, $tmpval) = each($menu_array)) {
//CODE HERE 
}
```

I have tried to update the code to look like this. But the issue I'm having is some menu selections put the website into an infinite loop.

```
while (list($tmpkey, $tmpval) = [key($menu_array), current($menu_array)]) {
//CODE HERE 
}
```

Just wondering if there is a better way to fix the issue and replicate what the original function did.

Comment: What's wrong with `foreach( $menu_array as $tmpkey => $tmpval )`?

Comment: "some menu selections" -- those should be clear from your [mcve]!

Comment: Cause of infinite loop is `key()` and `current()` do not move the array internal pointer. You can use `next($menu_array)` inside your `while` for doing it. But as others say, its better to use `foreach` instead of `while` in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foreach( $menu_array as $tmpkey => $tmpval )`